# 'int' object is not subscriptable in my AI project

Tags: python

It works perfectly in SUM variable in this function

```
def print_direction():
    global start_time
    stack = []
    i = end_pos[0]
    j = end_pos[1]

    SUM = int(mat[start_pos[0]][start_pos[1]]).data
    for m in range(mat_size):
        for n in range(mat_size):
            print(mat[m][n].kep, end="****")
        print()
    while i != start_pos[0] or j != start_pos[1]:
        SUM += mat[i][j].data
        stack.append(mat[i][j].direc)
        a = get_key(mat[i][j].direc)
        i -= a[0]
        j -= a[1]
    while stack:
        print(stack.pop(), end='-')
    if s == 1:
        S = "Yes"
    else:
        S = "No"
    print(" count_node: " + str(count_node) + " sum: " + str(SUM))

    ## Python program to print the data
    table = [
        ["Problem", "Heuristic name", "N", "d/N", "Success (Y/N)", "Time (sec)", "EBF", "avg H value", "Min", "Avg",
         "Max"], ["1", "straight line distance", count_node, format(deth / count_node, '.3f'), S,
                  format(time.time() - start_time, '.3f'), format(EBF / count_node, '.2f'),
                  format(E_Heuristic / time_act, '.2f'), Min, format(ave / help_ave, '.2f'), Max]]
    print(tabulate(table))
    print(help_ave)
    print(help_ave)
```

But not in this variable

```
temp1=int(mat[start_pos[0]][start_pos[1]]).data
```

Comment: Where do you set `start_pos`?

Comment: There's no way `SUM = int(mat[start_pos[0]][start_pos[1]]).data` works like you say it does. That line tries to access an attribute named `data` on an `int` object, which has no such attribute.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. We need to see how you're assigning all these variables.

Comment: Also, your `temp1` line (with the same bug) doesn't even show up in your posted code.

Comment: `'int' object is not subscriptable` is an error message that occurs when you try to use an int as an array i.e. indexing into an `int`. What you did with `SUM` is not the same, and even that should not work

Answer (score 0):

From the code you've posted, it looks like the correct solution is:

```
temp1=int(mat[start_pos[0]][start_pos[1]].data)
```

No conversion to `int` should be necessary, assuming this line `SUM += mat[i][j].data` in your code works as is

Comment: time_act = 1
count_node = 0
sum = 0
temp1=int(mat[start_pos[0]][start_pos[1]]).data
deth = 0
E_Heuristic = 0
EBF = 0
Min = math.inf
Max = 0
ave = 0
s = 0
help_ave = 0
# 11\10\01\-1-1\-10\0-1\1-1\-11
dic = {}

Comment: Im doing this outside a function. SUM is inside a function

Comment: print_direction() is one function. But temp1 is being declared outside a function